# Get svg graphics size when width/height attributes on <svg> are not set

Tags: javascript, svg

So how to get the size of an SVG file with javascript when width and height are not set on the svg element? The svg is a string, but could be made a DOM if necessary.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the getBBox() method of the SVGElement object.  It tells you the width and height, x, and y offset in pixels without taking into account the scaling of the element.

```
document.getElementById('myelem').getBBox().width  
document.getElementById('myelem').getBBox().height
```

are what you're looking for, I think.

EDIT:

1. I've recently also learned that the little known `getBoundingClientRect()` works as well!  You can also do: `var el = document.getElementById('myelem'); var mywidth = el.getBoundingClientRect().width;`
2. Keep in mind that there is a difference between getBBox and getBoundingClientRect. getBBox gets the initial dimensions - getBoundingClientRect also respects the **transformations** done with scale etc.

Comment: `getBBox` returns `{[..], width: 0, height: 0}` so does the `getBoundingClientRect`. The latter doesn't work only in FireFox.

Comment: Do not wrap your element with jQuery (like $(yourElement) ), as getBBox is not a function then.

Comment: You can use jQuery to select the element, you just need to add "[0]" after to get the non-jQuery dom element... i.e. $(yourElement)[0].getBoundingClientRect().height

Comment: jQuery is peripherally relevant at best.

Answer (score -3):

SVGs are *scalable* vector graphics, and thus can have any arbitrary height and width. Only the ratio is fixed by the format.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i know this, but in the SVG Viever widget i make(http://my.opera.com/SpShut/blog/show.dml/5803641) i need to display thumbnails of SVG files(say 100x100), and if a file has neither width/height nor viewBox attributes, it's displayed at *some size* and only 100x100 portion of it is visible. I want to process the file somehow to get the dimensions and set width/height and viewBox attributes.

Comment: You'll have to make an assumption about it then. If your thumbs are 100x100 then why not display the SVG at 100x100?

Comment: I set <object class="thumbnail" width="100px" height="100px" data="file.svg" /> and if the file.svg has no width&height&viewBox only 100x100 part if it is shown. I want to determine the size of graphics, set the attributes and rewrite the file on disk, so an assumption won't do. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: With no height and width set in the tag, there is no intrinsic size. You could look through each element in the svg and see what the largest x + width is and largest y + height, and call that the size. I'm not sure that you gain any advantages from that. Conceptually, what are you thinking of as size if not the intrinsic height and width?

Comment: Thanks, x+width & y+height is a nice variant! And yes, i mean i need to know intrinsic height and width. If i set the three attributes, the images will always fit into the dimensions of the object tag, instead of getting chopped off. 

And would you be so kind to write kind of an if-else algorithm to calculate the width and height, cause i'm not much of a programmer and wouldn't be able to figure it out myself. I've found a page that could be helpful http://my.opera.com/MacDev_ed/blog/getting-screen-boundingboxes-in-svg

And where is that button to give badges over here?

Comment: You can also try using an 'img' element instead of 'object', since that will automatically generate a viewBox for you as long as you have 'width' and 'height' set in the svg.